# Visual Composer for Wordpress CSS Revisions

Tags: css, wordpress, revisions

I am creating a project for work using Visual Composer for WordPress. My co-worker was messing around while I was in the middle of making changes and updated the page with old CSS, removing everything I had done for the entire day.

I noticed that WordPress has a revisions link, but it seems to only change the layout and not the 'Custom CSS' that was added. Before I give up and redo the entire thing, is there any way to go back?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you see it in "revisions" it's highly unlikely.

Comment: @douk not useful right now but you may want to look at having a copy of the website locally to develop against and investigate source control (git for example) to store revision changes through the day.

Comment: If you have access to your cPanel (hosting) then you could restore your website to the previous day.